# Gender neutrality in French adjectives

Tags: adjectifs, genre

I'm trying to teach a grade five class a unit about the family - labels at this point.  We have classified step parents/siblings using belle/beau and half-siblings as demi-, but I actually have a step-sibling who is non gendered and I don't know how to label that block.  I understand that adelphe is a term, meaning sibling, that is coming back into use because of this need for gender neutrality, but then to add the appendage of 'step', I then need to use beau/belle.  How do I resolve this?

Comment: https://divergenres.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/guide-grammaireinclusive-final.pdf is the most comprehensive document I've found. For the adjectives beau/belle it suggests belleaus. It also has another option for sibling: frœur. However, it doesn't combine these words for your specific case.

Comment: You are trying to say: non-gendered step-sibling in French?? The English term you use is what exactly? non-gendered is non-binaire, according to that "fount of wisdom" Wikipedia. But adelphe covers that too, as you say. demi-adelphe https://dictionnaire.orthodidacte.com/article/definition-adelphe

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it is possible in one word, but as a workaround you could use "par alliance" after the name, i.e. adelphe par alliance.

Comment: une identité de genre ( ex : personnes non binaire ), oui https://www.peaches.fr/lifestyle/healthy-life/quest-ce-que-le-concept-dadelphite-au-croisement-des-notions-de-sororite-et-fraternite-15511.html Mais pourquoi pas demi-adelphe?

Comment: @Earendelle I don't understand why you are commenting to me. The question is not that clear but one thing is clear: adelphe means sibling and demi means half or step. So my question to the person here is, why not: demi-adelphe? rather than par alliance.

Answer (score 1):

Step-brother/Step-sister is *demi-frère/demi-sœur* respectively. *Beau/belle* is used for in-laws.

So as suggested by Lambie, the word you're looking for is "*demi-adelphe*".

Comment: I do not understand why the OP does not just answer the question. Funny [odd], huh?

Comment: @Lambie Answer what question? I'm not following

Comment: See my comment under the question.

Comment: Why not add this to your answer and then I will remove it here? https://dictionnaire.orthodidacte.com/article/definition-adelphe

Answer (score 1):

On trouve diverses [pratiques d'écriture](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/50169/gender-neutrality-in-french-adjectives#comment103776_50169) qui pourraient permettre d'apporter des solutions mais elles restent surtout propres aux communautés de la diversité de genre ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=5370)) et avec le temps l'usage dira, et il faut donc généralement porter une attention à l'auditoire cible si on veut être compris...

L'[*adelphe*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/adelphe#Nom_commun) (aussi adj. [adelphe](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/adelphe), *amadelphe*, voire *adelphique*) pourrait être utile. On profitera aussi généralement du fait qu'un préfixe comme [*demi-*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1752) est invariable devant le nom.

On devrait nuancer entre [*quasi-*](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18075330)/[*demi-*](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18943056) selon la situation ; il faudrait aussi se rappeler qu'un même lexique, comme *[belle-](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/belle-)|[beau-](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/beau-)/[par alliance](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/par_alliance)*, peut englober des gens qui n'ont pas exactement la même « position » au sein d'une famille où d'autres termes pourraient être plus clairs mais ramèneraient à l'avant-plan la question du genre grammatical ([1](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=19008856), [2](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26559101), [3](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26559102)). Par ailleurs une réfection de certains [termes](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8423797) en science pourrait s'avérer utile pour regrouper différentes personnes sous la désignation d'un groupe.

À défaut de trouver les mots juste on a toujours des tours comme « [personne](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3986) faisant partie de » pouvant servir à créer des formulations inclusives (voir [aussi](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=%C3%A9pic%C3%A8ne&btn_chercher=CHERCHER)).

---

Generally I believe further analysis and planning is required to achieve more coherence througout the presentation to students.

Comment: J'ai remonté une coquille à l'OQLF, *demi-fratie* ;-)

Comment: Hahaha même en lisant ton commentaire je voyais le r... @jlliagre